# How to get the position and resolution of a disabled secondary monitor on Win7 x64 with C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, position, resolution, monitor

I need to get the position and resolution of a secondary monitor that is disabled.

Unfortunately `EnumDisplayMonitors` only works on enabled monitors. I know the position to be `(-1920, 0)` and the resolution to be `1920,1080`.

But I need to get it programmatically with C++ (Visual Studio 2012) so that it works on different computers with different monitors.

Comment: Maybe useful: http://superuser.com/questions/106749/what-registry-key-or-windows-file-determines-where-monitors-are-placed-in-a-mult

Comment: Unfortunately not really since I have no idea on how to reliably get the correct registry entry with the current settings on different computers.